# Python: Async function that works in script (__main__) and IPython

Tags: python

I am struggling to wrap my head around how to get a simple class to work in both IPython (I use spyder interactive interpreter, Jupyter notebook etc a lot), as well as a traditional script launched from command line.

At the top of my script, I have:

```
import asyncio
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()  # <--- from what I've seen, this is the easiest way to make async work in IPython.

    #Ultimately I'm trying to init this, and run net_position:

class Surfbird_DB():
    def __init__(self):        
        
        # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
        # MAIN ATTRIBUTES
        self.views = self._View_Models_Display()
        # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -            
    
    # - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    #2)  View Model functions / display

    class _View_Models_Display():
        def __init__(self):
            pass
        
        def __run(self, fx):
            return Surfbird_View_Result(asyncio.run(fx))
        
        @property
        def net_position(self):
            return self.__run(self.__get_net_position())
```

However, when I run this script, I get the following error in command line.

```
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'MainThread'.
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you replace
``nest_asyncio.apply()``
with
``nest_asyncio.apply(asyncio.new_event_loop())``

Comment: I may have found a way to do it.  I just put the nest_asyncio.apply() in the class __init__ within a try except block.  that way it called it whenever it was needed basically